# ArrayList does not store the second element

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to store the the latitude and longitude coordinates in an `ArrayList` to calculate the harversine formula between tow points after the first request but I am merely getting just one paar in it and I am getting the output `latLondList size: 1`. Maybe the code contains some Jersey notation but the question just deals with the java part.

`storeData` method:

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response storeData(Data data) {

    String macD = data.getMac();
    int routeD = data.getRoute();
    float latD = data.getLatitude();
    float longD = data.getLongitude();

    final ArrayList<LatLong> latLongList = new ArrayList<LatLong >();
    latLongList.add(new LatLong(latD, longD));

    System.out.println("latLondList size: "latLongList.size());

    Database db = new Database();
    db.insertData(macD, routeD, latD, longD);

    return Response.status(201).build();
}
```

`Data` class:

```
@Provider
public class Data {
    private String mac;
    private int route;
    private float latitude;
    private float longitude;
    // constructor with getter and setter
}
```

`LatLong` class:

```
public class LatLong {

    float latitude;
    float longitude;

    // constructor with getter and setter
}
```

**Edit:**

```
private ArrayList<LatLong> latLongList = new ArrayList<>();

@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response storeData(Data data) {

    String macD = data.getMac();
    int routeD = data.getRoute();
    float latD = data.getLatitude();
    float longD = data.getLongitude();

    latLongList.add(new LatLong(latD, longD));
}
```

Comment: You are adding one element to the list. What second value are you expecting?

Comment: Where are you adding a second element to `latLongList`?  What is the question?

Comment: You are creating a new ArrayList object for each iteration of the list. I think you are confused with `static` keyword in other languages and `final` in java. `final` does not mean there is only once instance of this object. Specifically, every time the method is invoked - a new list is created, and one element is pushed to it. You don't keep the array between two invokations.

Comment: You create a new empty list everytime you add a new pair.

Comment: You're creating a new ArrayList each time, so the previous is lost.

Comment: make you list globle(declare) out side the function.

Comment: @MuneebNasir: can you please see my edited code I am still getting `1` ?

Comment: how you access this storedata()? I mean, every time you create new object of the class?

Comment: can you provide code, where you invoking that storeData method?

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a new ArrayList object for each iteration of the list.

I think you are confused with `static` keyword in other languages and `final` in java. `final` does not mean there is only once instance of this object, it just means the value of the variable is initialized only once and cannot be changed during the variable's lifetime (in your example, it just says you cannot change the reference `latLongList` again in the method).

Specifically, every time the method is invoked - a new list is created, and one element is pushed to it. You don't keep the array between two invokations.

To overcome it, declare your `ArrayList` as an [instance variable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/variables.html), and create it only once - in construction of the object.

---

**EDIT** (response to edit to question)

In fact, when you declare in the method:

```
final ArrayList<LatLong> latLongList = new ArrayList<LatLong >();
```

You now say, "forget the instace veriable `latLongList` I declared, instead use this one.

This is NOT what you want to do, and the solution is simple - remove this line, and make the initialization `latLongList = new ArrayList<LatLong >()` in the constructor of the object.

One way to do it is to replace the line:

```
private ArrayList<LatLong> latLongList;
```

with

```
private ArrayList<LatLong> latLongList = new ArrayList<>(); //java7+
```

And of course, remove from the method the line:

```
final ArrayList<LatLong> latLongList = new ArrayList<LatLong >();
```

Comment: I declared it as global variable but it is still not working please see my edit code I am getting now `1` as output?!

Comment: @benz See edit, the reason is the same one, basically - you are using the method variable rather than the instance variable.

Comment: how to make the initialization in the constructor of the object? Please write the code in your answer to understand your point.

Comment: I have googled for `java initialization in the constructor of the object`  but didnot found solution because I dont have constructror to initialize it!

Comment: @benz You can (1) add constructor, or (2) use the syntatic sugar I suggested in the answer (which is equivalent to doing it in a constructor).

Comment: I used the sugar in your answer as in th edited code question but I am getting the same output `1`!

Comment: @benz Did you REMOVE the line I said you should remove as well?

Comment: Feeling like I'm being trolled

Comment: I have replaced it as you said in your edit answer `private ArrayList<LatLong> latLongList;` with `private ArrayList<LatLong> latLongList = new ArrayList<>();` and removed the another line  as in my edited code!

Comment: I dont still understand where my error is please take a look at my edit cide.

Answer (score 0):

```
private ArrayList<LatLong> latLongList = new ArrayList<LatLong>();
```

and comment out

```
//latLongList = new ArrayList<LatLong>();
```

Comment: You should explain why. This site teaches its visitors, not solving a single specific problem.